# RPScreenRecorder Recording alert text change

Tags: ios, recording, screen-recording, rpscreenrecorder

Do we have the possibility of changing the Recording alert text display by the RPSCreenRecorder in iOS 11?. Actually, I was capturing my application screen content using StartCapture API and pushing the video content to my server. But the Alert text is telling that: "You can save the recording to the camera roll or share it with the friends. Record microphone audio if you want to add comments as you go", which is not relevant to me. I want to change that text to something which is relevant to me.

Any info.plist keys for changing the text like for Privacy controls?

- Apparao Mulpuri

Answer (score 1):

For now you can't change the text and yes, this is strange, but you can give an alert (or tell user that he will be asked for this) before the system alert.